# Easy68K IF-ELSE branching

Tags: easy68k

writing my first assembly language program for class using Easy68K.

I'm using an if-else branching to replicate the code:

```
IF (P > 12)
    P = P * 8 + 3
ELSE
    P = P - Q

PRINT P
```

But I think I have my branches wrong because without the first halt in my code the program runs through the IF branch anyway even after the CMP finds a case that P < 12. Am I missing something here or would this be a generally accepted way of doing this?

Here is my assembly code:

```
START:  ORG     $1000       ; Program starts at loc $1000

        MOVE    P, D1       ; [D1] <- P
        MOVE    Q, D2       ; [D2] <- Q

* Program code here

        CMP     #12, D1     ; is P > 12?
        BGT     IF          ;
        SUB     D2, D1      ; P = P - Q

        MOVE    #3, D0      ; assign read command
        TRAP    #15         ;
        SIMHALT             ; halt simulator


IF      ASL     #3, D1      ; P = P * 8 
        ADD     #3, D1      ; P = P + 3
ENDIF

        MOVE    #3, D0      ; assign read command
        TRAP    #15         ;
        SIMHALT             ; halt simulator

* Data and Variables

        ORG     $2000       ; Data starts at loc $2000

P       DC.W    5           ;
Q       DC.W    7           ;

        END    START        ; last line of source
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do if..else, you need two jumps; one at the start, and one at the end of the first block.

While it doesn't affect correctness, it is also conventional to retain source order, which means negating the condition.

```
    MOVE    P, D1       ; [D1] <- P
    MOVE    Q, D2       ; [D2] <- Q

* Program code here

    CMP     #12, D1     ; is P > 12?
    BLE     ELSE        ; P is <= 12

IF
    ASL     #3, D1      ; P = P * 8 
    ADD     #3, D1      ; P = P + 3
    BRA     ENDIF

ELSE
    SUB     D2, D1      ; P = P - Q
ENDIF


    MOVE    #3, D0      ; assign read command
    TRAP    #15         ;
    SIMHALT             ; halt simulator
```

Comment: I see! I took notes in class where he used ENDIF as a branch name but I guess I just remembered it as an end command for the if without having to call it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EASy68K supports structured assembly.

```
OPT    SEX
IF.L P <GT> #12 THEN

ELSE

ENDI
```

Add the option SEX to expand the structured code during assembly if you wish to view the compare and branch instructions used to implement the structured code.